# JavaScript - Using Templates instead of Append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I went back and fourth on if this is CodeReview or not, and I don't think it is.

I was messing around with CodeSchool's newest AJAX Project and it got me thinking about templating. I'm a huge abuser of

```
$(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'someLink',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
      $.each(response.courses.completed, function(k,v){
       console.log(k,v)
       $('#badges').append('<div class="course"><h3>'+v.title+'</h3><img src="'+v.badge+'"><a href="'+v.url+'" class="btn btn-primary" target=_blank>See Course</a></div>')
      })
    }
  });

});
```

However, I see on some pages that I inspect, they instead will assign a blank set of `<div>`'s etc all named 'template'

**Example**

```
<div class="templates">
  <div class="deck-template">
    <div class="deck-item col-xs-12 col-md-4 filter">
      <div class="w3-card-4 totalDiv">
        <header class="w3-container w3-blue gameTitle">
          <h1 data-field="name"></h1>
        </header>
        <div class="w3-container imgContainer">
          <p>
            <img data-field="img" src="" class="gameImage" />
            <p class="bodyText" data-field="game-id"></p>
          </p>
          <p class="imageDiv">
            <div class="buttonContainer">
              <span class="viewerEntry">
                Want to watch someone?
                <button class="w3-btn w3-dark-grey viewerWatch">Some button text</button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </p>
        </div>
        <footer class="w3-container w3-blue gameFooter">
          <button class="detailButton w3-blue">
            <h5>Some Static Text</h5>
          </button>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This relies on heavy use of the .clone function. Is this a better method then using JS/jQ to append a ton of HTML Elements? I feel like it has to do with items being pre-loaded in the DOM rather than appended/bandwidth but I'm wondering about the logistics of 'why'.

Comment: Convenience mostly. Having the elements in the DOM means they are instantly accessible, and that you don't need to load another library to take care of retrieving a template and populating the data within it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Does `.clone`ing an already DOM-initiated element make it accessible any quicker? I'm trying to fully understand
You load the page - There is 10 elements in the DOM that are completely blank. Before any of the `.clone`'d elements render, you're still waiting for the jQ/JS+Script to load/render, right?

Comment: Don't understand what the question here is about? Are you having some kind of issue with some templating lib or something else?

Comment: No, it's marginally slower if anything due to the fact that accessing the DOM takes longer than building a string. However, if you're concerned about that level of performance you shouldn't be using jQuery at all.

Comment: Fair enough. I've just been wondering if I'm being an 'idiot' using .append like I am. It, without a doubt, makes the JS look extremely cluttered if I'm appending a lot, but functionality wise it seemed very similar.